# Angular 2+ service posting data to express route

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes, angular7

I am using Angular 7 and nodejs / express in a project.

I have mongodb running and I want to post some data from Angular to the exporess route so I can then process it and insert it to the database.

This is what I have in Angular service method:

Angular Service Post Data:

```
post() {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/insert', {name: 'paul'});
}
```

And this is in my Node/Express code:

```
app.get('/insert', (req, res) => {

    // code for getting the posted data so I can this process it

})
```

I need to grab the data posted from Angular.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know `node.js` but I think `app.get(...)` expects a `GET` request and from the frontend you're doint a `POST` request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client  (and dont forget to subscribe the call)

```
   post() {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/insert', {'name': 'paul'}, { headers: headers });
    }
```

nodejs

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/insert', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.name);
})
```